# SQL: Wrong output

Tags: sql

I have written a query but I get wrong results.

These are the tables:

```
|actor|-->|role|-->|movie|->|movie_has_genre|-->|genre|
```

In each table I have (table: fields):

```
actor: actor_id
role: actor_id, movie_id
movie:movie_id
movie_has_genre: movie_id, genre_id
genre: genre_id
```

I'm looking to find the actors' ids that have played in all kinds of movies.

My code is:

```
SELECT a.actor_id
FROM actor a
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
SELECT *
FROM genre g
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM movie m
    WHERE m.movie_id in(
        SELECT m1.movie_id
        FROM movie m1, role r, movie_has_genre mg
        WHERE a.actor_id=r.actor_id AND r.movie_id=m1.movie_id 
        AND m1.movie_id=mg.movie_id AND mg.genre_id=g.genre_id))        
);
```

Can you help?

Comment: Can you define: wrong results? Also, create a http://sqlfiddle.com for us please

Comment: Is is `genre` or `gender`? Looks like you meant genre...

Comment: When I say wrong results i mean that i know the correct ones and i get wrong ones. And its genre not gender...

Comment: @a_user: Any example data?

Comment: For example: 
Correct results:
12365
784567
2784
756
37546

But i get :
23465
NULL

Comment: You would propably need a simple join statement but define the result. What does it mean: all kinds of movies?

Comment: Genre is the kind of movie: Drama, Comedy, etc. What i mean is to find the actors that "connect" with all the different genre_ids.

Answer (score 0):

It's pseudo code but you can get the idea

```
select a.actor_id, count(mg.genre_id) as countkinds
from actor a
join role r on r.actor_id = a.actor_id
join movie_has_genre mg on mg.movie_id =r.movie_id
group by a.actor_id
having count(mg.genre_id) = (select count(*) from genre)
```

just join actors to genre_ids, count it and return only all played in all genres.

note you don't need to join movies table since you can join role and movie_has_genre for the same movie directly by the id

Comment: Thanks for the help , I will see how I can use it.